# Source Code vs Compiled Code

Tags: ios, compilation

I am noticing something I've never seen before, and I'm hoping someone can clarify exactly what's going on.

I put iOS 6 on my development device and then downloaded my app from the App Store. That app was created in an older version of Xcode without the iOS 6 SDK. It runs fine on my device when I go get it.

However, I now have Xcode 4.5 with the iOS 6 SDK. I open my old Xcode project, which has the same exact source code used to build the app in the app store - no changes to the code whatsoever. When I run this project again on my iOS 6 device, from Xcode, the app is buggy and does not at all behave as expected.

I know the source code is the same, so is this a result of different compiled binaries due to different SDKs?

Comment: The compiler did change, the Frameworks did change, the APIs did change. You really shouldn't expect the same binary.

Comment: So in short, one shouldn't be too worried about an old binary behaving as expected vs a new binary from the old source code.

Comment: It really depends - once Apple updated the iOS even some of my older Apps in Appstore behaved differntly on the new iOS, while a new compile with the new SDK sometimes fixes it, sometimes not. In these cases I even had to slightly redesign some delegate scheme. So in summary, I guess you either test all configurations yourself or wait until you get the first comment in a review ...which happened to me, since I wrongly relied on compatibility with the new releases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a developer beta of every major version active for months before public release for reason.

A lot has changed with Xcode 4.5. iOS SDK 6.0 has [**many** changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/index.html) (iOS Developer Program required to open link), armv6 support (architecture used by iPhone 3G and older models) is gone, compiler has some new features and so on.

In short, it's normal that code requires some maintenance when tools change.